# How to run spark-shell with YARN in client mode?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I've installed `spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz` on a 15-node Hadoop cluster. All nodes run `Java 1.8.0_72` and the latest version of Hadoop. The Hadoop cluster itself is functional, e.g. YARN can run various MapReduce jobs successfully.

I can run Spark Shell locally on a node without any problems with the following command: `$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell`.

I can also run some Spark examples successfully, such as SparkPi using  YARN and cluster mode.

But when I try to run Spark Shell on YARN with deploy mode `client`, I encounter problems:

```
hadoopu@hadoop2:~$ $SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell --master yarn --deploy-mode client
16/03/21 15:15:20 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
...
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.6.1
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.10.5 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_72)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
...
16/03/21 15:15:24 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 511.1 MB
16/03/21 15:15:24 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
16/03/21 15:15:24 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
16/03/21 15:15:24 INFO SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://10.108.57.32:4040
16/03/21 15:15:24 INFO RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at hadoop2/10.108.57.32:8032
16/03/21 15:15:24 INFO Client: Requesting a new application from cluster with 13 NodeManagers
16/03/21 15:15:25 INFO Client: Verifying our application has not requested more than the maximum memory capability of the cluster (131072 MB per container)
16/03/21 15:15:25 INFO Client: Will allocate AM container, with 896 MB memory including 384 MB overhead
16/03/21 15:15:25 INFO Client: Setting up container launch context for our AM
16/03/21 15:15:25 INFO Client: Setting up the launch environment for our AM container
16/03/21 15:15:25 INFO Client: Preparing resources for our AM container
16/03/21 15:15:25 WARN DomainSocketFactory: The short-circuit local reads feature cannot be used because libhadoop cannot be loaded.
16/03/21 15:15:25 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/opt/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/spark-assembly-1.6.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar -> hdfs://hadoop1:9000/user/hadoopu/.sparkStaging/application_1458568053208_0006/spark-assembly-1.6.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar
16/03/21 15:15:28 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/tmp/spark-c9077c60-b379-439e-aeb4-85948df70df5/__spark_conf__7479505398141092205.zip -> hdfs://hadoop1:9000/user/hadoopu/.sparkStaging/application_1458568053208_0006/__spark_conf__7479505398141092205.zip
16/03/21 15:15:28 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: hadoopu
16/03/21 15:15:28 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: hadoopu
16/03/21 15:15:28 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(hadoopu); users with modify permissions: Set(hadoopu)
16/03/21 15:15:28 INFO Client: Submitting application 6 to ResourceManager
16/03/21 15:15:28 INFO YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1458568053208_0006
16/03/21 15:15:29 INFO Client: Application report for application_1458568053208_0006 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/03/21 15:15:29 INFO Client:
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: AM container is launched, waiting for AM container to Register with RM
     ApplicationMaster host: N/A
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
     queue: default
     start time: 1458569728506
     final status: UNDEFINED
     tracking URL: http://hadoop2:8088/proxy/application_1458568053208_0006/
     user: hadoopu
16/03/21 15:15:30 INFO Client: Application report for application_1458568053208_0006 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/03/21 15:15:31 INFO Client: Application report for application_1458568053208_0006 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/03/21 15:15:32 INFO YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: ApplicationMaster registered as NettyRpcEndpointRef(null)
16/03/21 15:15:32 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Add WebUI Filter. org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter, Map(PROXY_HOSTS -> hadoop2, PROXY_URI_BASES -> http://hadoop2:8088/proxy/application_1458568053208_0006), /proxy/application_1458568053208_0006
16/03/21 15:15:32 INFO JettyUtils: Adding filter: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter
16/03/21 15:15:32 INFO Client: Application report for application_1458568053208_0006 (state: RUNNING)
16/03/21 15:15:32 INFO Client:
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: N/A
     ApplicationMaster host: 10.108.57.41
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: 0
     queue: default
     start time: 1458569728506
     final status: UNDEFINED
     tracking URL: http://hadoop2:8088/proxy/application_1458568053208_0006/
     user: hadoopu
16/03/21 15:15:32 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Application application_1458568053208_0006 has started running.
16/03/21 15:15:32 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 50170.
16/03/21 15:15:32 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 50170
16/03/21 15:15:32 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
16/03/21 15:15:32 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 10.108.57.32:50170 with 511.1 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 10.108.57.32, 50170)
16/03/21 15:15:32 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
16/03/21 15:15:37 INFO YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: ApplicationMaster registered as NettyRpcEndpointRef(null)
16/03/21 15:15:37 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Add WebUI Filter. org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter, Map(PROXY_HOSTS -> hadoop2, PROXY_URI_BASES -> http://hadoop2:8088/proxy/application_1458568053208_0006), /proxy/application_1458568053208_0006
16/03/21 15:15:37 INFO JettyUtils: Adding filter: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter
16/03/21 15:15:39 ERROR YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Yarn application has already exited with state FINISHED!
16/03/21 15:15:39 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://10.108.57.32:4040
16/03/21 15:15:39 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Shutting down all executors
16/03/21 15:15:39 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Asking each executor to shut down
16/03/21 15:15:39 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Stopped
16/03/21 15:15:39 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
16/03/21 15:15:39 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
16/03/21 15:15:39 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
16/03/21 15:15:39 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
16/03/21 15:15:39 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
16/03/21 15:15:39 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
16/03/21 15:15:39 INFO RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Shutting down remote daemon.
16/03/21 15:15:39 INFO RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Remote daemon shut down; proceeding with flushing remote transports.
16/03/21 15:15:39 INFO RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Remoting shut down.
16/03/21 15:15:54 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after waiting maxRegisteredResourcesWaitingTime: 30000(ms)
16/03/21 15:15:54 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:584)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.createSparkContext(SparkILoop.scala:1017)
    at $line3.$read$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:15)
    at $line3.$read$$iwC.<init>(<console>:24)
    at $line3.$read.<init>(<console>:26)
    at $line3.$read$.<init>(<console>:30)
    at $line3.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
    at $line3.$eval$.<init>(<console>:7)
    at $line3.$eval$.<clinit>(<console>)
    at $line3.$eval.$print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1346)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoopInit.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoopInit.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.beQuietDuring(SparkIMain.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.initializeSpark(SparkILoopInit.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$5.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:974)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.runThunks(SparkILoopInit.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.runThunks(SparkILoop.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.postInitialization(SparkILoopInit.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.postInitialization(SparkILoop.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:991)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
16/03/21 15:15:54 INFO SparkContext: SparkContext already stopped.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:584)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.createSparkContext(SparkILoop.scala:1017)
    at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:15)
    at $iwC.<init>(<console>:24)
    at <init>(<console>:26)
    at .<init>(<console>:30)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1346)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoopInit.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoopInit.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.beQuietDuring(SparkIMain.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.initializeSpark(SparkILoopInit.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$5.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:974)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.runThunks(SparkILoopInit.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.runThunks(SparkILoop.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.postInitialization(SparkILoopInit.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.postInitialization(SparkILoop.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:991)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$.createListenerAndUI(SQLContext.scala:1367)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.<init>(HiveContext.scala:101)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.createSQLContext(SparkILoop.scala:1028)
    at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:15)
    at $iwC.<init>(<console>:24)
    at <init>(<console>:26)
    at .<init>(<console>:30)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1346)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoopInit.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoopInit.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.beQuietDuring(SparkIMain.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.initializeSpark(SparkILoopInit.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$5.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:974)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.runThunks(SparkILoopInit.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.runThunks(SparkILoop.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.postInitialization(SparkILoopInit.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.postInitialization(SparkILoop.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:991)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

<console>:16: error: not found: value sqlContext
         import sqlContext.implicits._
                ^
<console>:16: error: not found: value sqlContext
         import sqlContext.sql
                ^

scala>

scala> sc
<console>:20: error: not found: value sc
              sc
              ^

scala>
```

I've also went to the YARN Web UI, found the Spark Shell in the list of FINISHED applications, then clicked on the application to see the logs. I've found two nodes with `stderr` logs:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/mnt/ssd1/tmp/nm-local-dir/usercache/hadoopu/filecache/13/spark-assembly-1.6.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/hadoop-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
16/03/21 15:07:20 INFO ApplicationMaster: Registered signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
16/03/21 15:07:21 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/03/21 15:07:21 INFO ApplicationMaster: ApplicationAttemptId: appattempt_1458568053208_0005_000002
16/03/21 15:07:22 WARN DomainSocketFactory: The short-circuit local reads feature cannot be used because libhadoop cannot be loaded.
16/03/21 15:07:22 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: hadoopu
16/03/21 15:07:22 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: hadoopu
16/03/21 15:07:22 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(hadoopu); users with modify permissions: Set(hadoopu)
16/03/21 15:07:22 INFO ApplicationMaster: Waiting for Spark driver to be reachable.
16/03/21 15:07:22 INFO ApplicationMaster: Driver now available: 10.108.57.32:39824
16/03/21 15:07:22 INFO ApplicationMaster$AMEndpoint: Add WebUI Filter. AddWebUIFilter(org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter,Map(PROXY_HOSTS -> hadoop2, PROXY_URI_BASES -> http://hadoop2:8088/proxy/application_1458568053208_0005),/proxy/application_1458568053208_0005)
16/03/21 15:07:22 INFO RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at hadoop2/10.108.57.32:8030
16/03/21 15:07:22 INFO YarnRMClient: Registering the ApplicationMaster
16/03/21 15:07:22 INFO YarnAllocator: Will request 2 executor containers, each with 1 cores and 1408 MB memory including 384 MB overhead
16/03/21 15:07:22 INFO YarnAllocator: Container request (host: Any, capability: <memory:1408, vCores:1>)
16/03/21 15:07:22 INFO YarnAllocator: Container request (host: Any, capability: <memory:1408, vCores:1>)
16/03/21 15:07:22 INFO ApplicationMaster: Started progress reporter thread with (heartbeat : 3000, initial allocation : 200) intervals
16/03/21 15:07:23 INFO AMRMClientImpl: Received new token for : hadoop14:32420
16/03/21 15:07:23 INFO AMRMClientImpl: Received new token for : hadoop3:35904
16/03/21 15:07:23 INFO YarnAllocator: Launching container container_1458568053208_0005_02_000002 for on host hadoop14
16/03/21 15:07:23 INFO YarnAllocator: Launching ExecutorRunnable. driverUrl: spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@10.108.57.32:39824,  executorHostname: hadoop14
16/03/21 15:07:23 INFO YarnAllocator: Launching container container_1458568053208_0005_02_000003 for on host hadoop3
16/03/21 15:07:23 INFO ExecutorRunnable: Starting Executor Container
16/03/21 15:07:23 INFO YarnAllocator: Launching ExecutorRunnable. driverUrl: spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@10.108.57.32:39824,  executorHostname: hadoop3
16/03/21 15:07:23 INFO ExecutorRunnable: Starting Executor Container
16/03/21 15:07:23 INFO YarnAllocator: Received 2 containers from YARN, launching executors on 2 of them.
16/03/21 15:07:23 INFO ContainerManagementProtocolProxy: yarn.client.max-cached-nodemanagers-proxies : 0
16/03/21 15:07:23 INFO ContainerManagementProtocolProxy: yarn.client.max-cached-nodemanagers-proxies : 0
16/03/21 15:07:23 INFO ExecutorRunnable: Setting up ContainerLaunchContext
16/03/21 15:07:23 INFO ExecutorRunnable: Setting up ContainerLaunchContext
16/03/21 15:07:23 INFO ExecutorRunnable: Preparing Local resources
16/03/21 15:07:23 INFO ExecutorRunnable: Preparing Local resources
16/03/21 15:07:23 INFO ExecutorRunnable: Prepared Local resources Map(__spark__.jar -> resource { scheme: "hdfs" host: "hadoop1" port: 9000 file: "/user/hadoopu/.sparkStaging/application_1458568053208_0005/spark-assembly-1.6.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar" } size: 187698038 timestamp: 1458569230874 type: FILE visibility: PRIVATE)
16/03/21 15:07:23 INFO ExecutorRunnable: Prepared Local resources Map(__spark__.jar -> resource { scheme: "hdfs" host: "hadoop1" port: 9000 file: "/user/hadoopu/.sparkStaging/application_1458568053208_0005/spark-assembly-1.6.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar" } size: 187698038 timestamp: 1458569230874 type: FILE visibility: PRIVATE)
16/03/21 15:07:23 INFO ExecutorRunnable: 
===============================================================================
YARN executor launch context:
  env:
    CLASSPATH -> {{PWD}}<CPS>{{PWD}}/__spark__.jar<CPS>$HADOOP_CONF_DIR<CPS>$HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/share/hadoop/common/*<CPS>$HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/share/hadoop/common/lib/*<CPS>$HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/share/hadoop/hdfs/*<CPS>$HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*<CPS>$HADOOP_YARN_HOME/share/hadoop/yarn/*<CPS>$HADOOP_YARN_HOME/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*<CPS>$HADOOP_PREFIX/share/hadoop/tools/lib/*<CPS>$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*<CPS>$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*
    SPARK_LOG_URL_STDERR -> http://hadoop3:8042/node/containerlogs/container_1458568053208_0005_02_000003/hadoopu/stderr?start=-4096
    SPARK_YARN_STAGING_DIR -> .sparkStaging/application_1458568053208_0005
    SPARK_YARN_CACHE_FILES_FILE_SIZES -> 187698038
    SPARK_USER -> hadoopu
    SPARK_YARN_CACHE_FILES_VISIBILITIES -> PRIVATE
    SPARK_YARN_MODE -> true
    SPARK_YARN_CACHE_FILES_TIME_STAMPS -> 1458569230874
    SPARK_LOG_URL_STDOUT -> http://hadoop3:8042/node/containerlogs/container_1458568053208_0005_02_000003/hadoopu/stdout?start=-4096
    SPARK_YARN_CACHE_FILES -> hdfs://hadoop1:9000/user/hadoopu/.sparkStaging/application_1458568053208_0005/spark-assembly-1.6.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar#__spark__.jar

  command:
    {{JAVA_HOME}}/bin/java -server -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill %p' -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -Djava.io.tmpdir={{PWD}}/tmp '-Dspark.driver.port=39824' -Dspark.yarn.app.container.log.dir=<LOG_DIR> org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend --driver-url spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@10.108.57.32:39824 --executor-id 2 --hostname hadoop3 --cores 1 --app-id application_1458568053208_0005 --user-class-path file:$PWD/__app__.jar 1> <LOG_DIR>/stdout 2> <LOG_DIR>/stderr
===============================================================================

16/03/21 15:07:23 INFO ExecutorRunnable: 
===============================================================================
YARN executor launch context:
  env:
    CLASSPATH -> {{PWD}}<CPS>{{PWD}}/__spark__.jar<CPS>$HADOOP_CONF_DIR<CPS>$HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/share/hadoop/common/*<CPS>$HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/share/hadoop/common/lib/*<CPS>$HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/share/hadoop/hdfs/*<CPS>$HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*<CPS>$HADOOP_YARN_HOME/share/hadoop/yarn/*<CPS>$HADOOP_YARN_HOME/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*<CPS>$HADOOP_PREFIX/share/hadoop/tools/lib/*<CPS>$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*<CPS>$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*
    SPARK_LOG_URL_STDERR -> http://hadoop14:8042/node/containerlogs/container_1458568053208_0005_02_000002/hadoopu/stderr?start=-4096
    SPARK_YARN_STAGING_DIR -> .sparkStaging/application_1458568053208_0005
    SPARK_YARN_CACHE_FILES_FILE_SIZES -> 187698038
    SPARK_USER -> hadoopu
    SPARK_YARN_CACHE_FILES_VISIBILITIES -> PRIVATE
    SPARK_YARN_MODE -> true
    SPARK_YARN_CACHE_FILES_TIME_STAMPS -> 1458569230874
    SPARK_LOG_URL_STDOUT -> http://hadoop14:8042/node/containerlogs/container_1458568053208_0005_02_000002/hadoopu/stdout?start=-4096
    SPARK_YARN_CACHE_FILES -> hdfs://hadoop1:9000/user/hadoopu/.sparkStaging/application_1458568053208_0005/spark-assembly-1.6.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar#__spark__.jar

  command:
    {{JAVA_HOME}}/bin/java -server -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill %p' -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -Djava.io.tmpdir={{PWD}}/tmp '-Dspark.driver.port=39824' -Dspark.yarn.app.container.log.dir=<LOG_DIR> org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend --driver-url spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@10.108.57.32:39824 --executor-id 1 --hostname hadoop14 --cores 1 --app-id application_1458568053208_0005 --user-class-path file:$PWD/__app__.jar 1> <LOG_DIR>/stdout 2> <LOG_DIR>/stderr
===============================================================================
...
16/03/21 15:07:25 ERROR ApplicationMaster: RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM
16/03/21 15:07:25 INFO ApplicationMaster: Final app status: UNDEFINED, exitCode: 0, (reason: Shutdown hook called before final status was reported.)
16/03/21 15:07:25 INFO ApplicationMaster: Unregistering ApplicationMaster with UNDEFINED (diag message: Shutdown hook called before final status was reported.)
16/03/21 15:07:25 INFO AMRMClientImpl: Waiting for application to be successfully unregistered.
16/03/21 15:07:25 INFO ApplicationMaster: Deleting staging directory .sparkStaging/application_1458568053208_0005
16/03/21 15:07:25 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
```

Any ideas why I can't run Spark Shell on YARN with client mode?

Comment: Your executors have run out of memory. You should be able to supply argument for executor memory and worker memory on spark-shell.

Comment: I don't see any problems regarding memory in the logs. Can you point at the lines that shows an out of memory error? In the meantime, I've also tried `spark-shell --master yarn --deploy-mode client --driver-memory 512m --executor-memory 512m` only to get a similar, problematic result. The nodes have 128 GB of RAM, and I can't see any Out of Memory messages.

Comment: I think you're showing logs from two different applications, i.e. the spark-shell logs are for `application_1458568053208_0006` while from YARN for `appattempt_1458568053208_0005_000002` which I believe is for the earlier (probably successful) execution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  It turned out to be a firewall between my login node and the cluster: the cluster was trying to connect back to the login node on a random port that was blocked.  Either remove the firewall rules, or move your shell to one of the nodes of the cluster where there aren't any firewall rules that block access.